# how to disable touchpad while using the trackpoint?

Tags: touchpad, thinkpad

I'm pretty new in Linux and bash and I am very satisfied with my elementaryOS. I have a small problem. I need to disable the touchpad when I'm using the trackpoint. I am using Freya on Thinkpad X1 Carbon 1st Gen.
Any help will be much appreciated..